# How to search shared mailbox based on Excel cell values?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to search Outlook shared mailboxes based on the cell value in range A:A then write a "Y" or "N" to B:B depending on whether it finds something.
I would like to search in body and subject as well.

For example: In cell A1 there is a number 1111123 to search in shared mailboxes.
If a match is found write a "Y" to cell B1, if not, write a "N".
Then go to cell A2, A3, A4, etc. till the last cell in range A:A and write the results to B2, B3, B4, etc.

This code searches Outlook for the value in the active cell and writes a "Y" or a "N" to range B1.

1. I want the macro not only to find the value of the active cell, but the value of the whole column A. cell by cell.
2. This is slow. It takes around 3-5 min to find the cell value.

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public Sub Search_Outlook_Emails()
    
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim outStartFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim foundEmail As Outlook.MailItem
        
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")     
    
    Set outStartFolder = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.olFolderInbox).Parent    
      
    'Set outStartFolder = outNs.PickFolder
    
    If Not outStartFolder Is Nothing Then
            
        Set foundEmail = Find_Email_In_Folder(outStartFolder, ActiveCell.Value)
            
        If Not foundEmail Is Nothing Then
            Range("B1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Y"    
        End If
                
    Else
            
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N"
                
    End If
    
End Sub
    
    
Private Function Find_Email_In_Folder(outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, findText As String) As Outlook.MailItem
        
    Dim outItem As Object
    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim outSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long
        
    Debug.Print outFolder.FolderPath
        
    Set Find_Email_In_Folder = Nothing
        
    'Search emails in this folder
        
    i = 1
    While i <= outFolder.Items.Count And Find_Email_In_Folder Is Nothing
        
        Set outItem = outFolder.Items(i)
                    
        If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
                
            'Does the findText occur in this email's body text?
                           
            Set outMail = outItem
            If InStr(1, outMail.Body, findText, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Set Find_Email_In_Folder = outMail
                
        End If
            
        i = i + 1
            
    Wend
        
    DoEvents
        
    'If not found, search emails in subfolders
        
    i = 1
    While i <= outFolder.Folders.Count And Find_Email_In_Folder Is Nothing
        
        Set outSubFolder = outFolder.Folders(i)
            
        'Only check mail item folders
            
        If outSubFolder.DefaultItemType = Outlook.olMailItem Then Set Find_Email_In_Folder = Find_Email_In_Folder(outSubFolder, findText)
        
        i = i + 1
            
    Wend
        
End Function
```

Comment: Can you provide more specific details about which aspects of the Outlook Object Model you are having difficulty with? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, but if you rephrase your question and show the code or research you've done so far you will have a better chance of getting a response.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1):

Never loop through all items in a folder, always use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`. In your case, the query would be

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1000001F" LIKE '%Some value%'
```

The DASL name above corresponds to the `PR_BODY_W` MAPI property (you cannot use `Body` OOM name in a query).

If you want matches on multiple values, your need to create an appropriate query using "OR" and/or "AND" operators.